# On desktop browser, emulate Android's large font size

Tags: android-emulator, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way in desktop Chrome (or other browsers) to emulate Android where someone has chosen a large font size in their settings? Or small, for that matter.

I know I can choose an Android (such as Pixel 7) in the Chrome Inspect/DevTools, but I don't see a way to a emulate different font setting sizes.